# Is there a TSLint rule that forbids the prefixed type assertion syntax?

Tags: typescript, tslint

Type assertion can be described in two ways:

1. Prefixed

```js
<Foo>{ foo: 'bar' };
```

2. Suffixed

```js
{ foo: 'bar' } as Foo;
```

Are there any TSLint rules that forbid the former and enforce the latter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TSLint has a builtin rule for this very thing: [no-angle-bracket-type-assertion](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/no-angle-bracket-type-assertion/)

To enable, add the rule to your `tslint.json` as follows

```
{
  "rules": {
    "no-angle-bracket-type-assertion": true
  }
}
```

There is an auto-fixer for the rule.